# Android see HTTP like in Chrome dev tool

Tags: android, ddms, androidhttpclient

Is there a way to see my app HTTP traffic like in the Chrome development tool for websites?

I want to see the requests and the responses.

I tried the DDMS network tools but it shows only the amount of network and not the data(requests and the responses).

Comment: At work we use CharlesProxy for that but you need a license. I guess Wireshark would do, but it is more low level. I don't think there is a solution in Studio or the sdk (it would be basically a http proxy).

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the solution. as Gil Vegliach  suggested I looked for proxy.
the instructions are here:
http://blog.eviltester.com/2013/10/how-to-view-http-traffic-on-your-mobile.html

**note: when enabling "remote connections" you must restart the proxy**